# How to trigger additional PR commit builds in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am building a DevOps pipeline through yaml file which triggers a build for PR. Structure below:

```
pr:
  - dev2
stages:
- stage: PR
  condition: and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
  displayName: prBuild
  jobs:
   - job: DowndSecureFile
```

if i raise a PR for the first time to the **dev2** branch from another branch ex: **dev3** it triggers.

Another build fails to trigger in this case:
If the PR is not yet merged:
and I have made additional commit to **dev3** then build is **skipped** for the PR
I understand this is due to this condition where Build.Reason changes to CI:

```
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
```

But I am trying to do, that if a pr is still open and if i put additional commits to the PR branch **dev3**, i need to trigger a build again for that PR. Is there any suitable condition for that? or

**Update:**

I am using github enterprise, for the repository, no Azure Repos is used here.

should i do something else?

Can anyone help me here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `Build.Reason` variable have a value of `PullRequest` when the build is triggered by a branch policy as indicated in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation) shows how you can setup build validation as a part of your branch policy. The branch policy helps ensure the PR can only be merged if the build is succesful and also require a minimum number of code reviewers.

The manual describes that a new build is triggered for each updated commit to the pull request.

Comment: Wich of the dev2 or dev3 branch did you set Build validation? From your yaml demo, you set build validation on dev2, but you put additional commits to the PR branch dev3 , does it mean you have set build validation on dev3 ?

Comment: @Roderick Bant, thank you, i am not using azure repos here, only github enterprise . updated the questions

Answer (score 0):

@Roderick Bant has given the doc for `Build.Reason`.On the base of his answer, i want to make additional information.
If you want to trigger a build for both PR and CI, you can modify your condition:

```
condition: and(succeeded(), in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest', 'IndividualCI'))
```